# Is there a specific definition of short run and long run?

Tags: definition

Like normally how long can be said as long run? And does specific time length of these words matters?

Answer (score 2):

The actual length of time does not matter. Simply, in the short-run capital is fixed and labor is variable. In the long-run both capital and labor are variable (which gives firms enough time to, for example, build a new factory to match an increase in demand). It would be really fortunate if there was a general time frame, but that would vary from industry to industry. The long-run for, let say, Ford is a pretty long-time because they are very capital intensive. However the long-run for, lets say, a Clown Rental Service, is very short because it is entirely labor dependent.

Hopefully this answer helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation! I also just read about a definition saying that normally in a short-term we assume that at least one input is fixed, from the Advanced Microeconomic Theory by Jehle and Reny.

Comment: Ya, that would be tue slightly more general definition. But the sr case where labor is fixed and capital varies is a rare, odd case